# Submitting two forms on page with only one button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms

I am building an example webshop application to learn angularjs. In the actual learning step i am implementing the View with forms for the shipping address and billing address. There are two forms on the view. One for the Shipping address and one for the billing address. As standard the billing address is the same as the shipping address. Only when the user clicks on the button "change billing address" he should have the option to choose another address for the bills. Here I have two questions:

1) When I put in a shipping address  in the form "orderAddressForm" and then click on "change billing address" the second form "orderBillingAddressForm" is shown correctly. But when I put in something here then the input of the first form "orderAddressForm" is changed too. Why is this happening? Both forms are bound to different variables???

2) When I click the button "Submit" button then there is no validation happening. I would like that every seen form is validated after I click this one "submit" button.

Here is the plunkr link: [Plunkr Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/rKcDqJ?p=info)

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css"  
  />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" 
  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"> 
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="form-group">
                <label>Shipping address</label>
              </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form name="orderAddressForm" ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label>Salutation</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <select name="salutation" ng-
               model="shippingAddress.salutation" required="" class="form-
               control">
                <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
                <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
              </select>
              <span ng-show="(orderAddressForm.salutation.$dirty && 
              submitted) && orderAddressForm.salutation.$error.required">
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label>Firstname</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input type="text" name="prename" ng-
               model="shippingAddress.prename" required="" class="form-
               control" />
              <span ng-show="(orderAddressForm.prename.$dirty && submitted) 
               && orderAddressForm.prename.$error.required"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label>Lastname</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input type="text" name="surname" ng-
               model="shippingAddress.surname" required="" class="form-
               control" />
              <span ng-show="(orderAddressForm.surname.$dirty && submitted) 
               && orderAddressForm.surname.$error.required"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="form-group">
              <label>Billing address</label>
              <button ng-click="setBillingAddress()" ng-
               show="changeBillingAddress === false" class="btn btn-default 
               pull-right">Change billingaddress</button>
              <button ng-click="cancelBillingAddress()" ng-
               show="changeBillingAddress === true" class="btn btn-danger 
               pull-right">Cancel</button>
            </h3>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="changeBillingAddress === false" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1">Identisch mit Lieferadresse</div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="changeBillingAddress === true" class="row">
        <div style="margin-top: 5px">
          <form name="orderBillingAddressForm" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="row">
              <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : billingSubmitted && 
               orderBillingAddressForm.salutation.$invalid}" class="form-
               group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Salutation</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <select name="salutation" ng-
                   model="billingAddress.salutation" required="" 
                   class="form-control">
                    <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
                    <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                  </select>
                  <p ng-show="orderBillingAddressForm.salutation.$invalid && 
                  !orderBillingAddressForm.salutation.$pristine && 
                  billingSubmitted" class="help-block">Pflichtfeld</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : billingSubmitted && 
               orderBillingAddressForm.prename.$invalid}" class="form-
               group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Firstname</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="prename" ng-
                    model="billingAddress.prename" required="" class="form-
                    control" />
                  <p ng-show="orderBillingAddressForm.prename.$invalid && 
                   !orderBillingAddressForm.prename.$pristine && 
                   billingSubmitted" class="help-block">Pflichtfeld .row</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Lastname</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="surname" ng-
                   model="billingAddress.surname" required="" class="form-
                   control" />
                  <span ng-show="(orderBillingAddressForm.surname.$dirty && 
                   submitted) && 
                   orderBillingAddressForm.surname.$error.required"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div style="padding-top: 1em">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-
           right">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.billingAdrEqualsShippingAdr = false;

     $scope.confirmBillingEqualsShipping = true;
     $scope.changeBillingAddress = false;

     $scope.shippingAddress = {};

     $scope.setBillingAddress = function (){
       $scope.changeBillingAddress = true;
         $scope.billingAddress = $scope.shippingAddress;
     };

     $scope.cancelBillingAddress = function (){
       $scope.changeBillingAddress = false;
         $scope.billingAddress = $scope.shippingAddress;
     };

     $scope.openCompanyModal = function (company){
         $scope.billingAddress = company;
         $scope.shippingAddress = company;
     };

    $scope.submit = function (){
      console.log("Form submitted");
    }
});
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in Advance,

YB

Comment: Concept of using 2 forms is  wrong. Browser can only submit one form and validation will only occur on the one form that is actually submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "ng-form" for organizing your forms and just add a button on the end which will call that 'submit()' function you use.

```
<div ng-form="form1">
 form1 fields
</div>

<div ng-form="form2">
 form2 fields
</div>

<button ng-click="submit()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='form1'>
  ....something
</form>

<form id='form2'>
  .... something
</form>

<div id='btnDiv'>
  <button id='btn1' ng-click="Submit-Forms">
</div>

//in JS
On click of #btn1, invoke/execute the functions (directly) of the two forms
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are assigning shippingAddress to BillingAddress here, you should not do that.

```
 $scope.setBillingAddress = function (){
   $scope.changeBillingAddress = true;
   //$scope.billingAddress = $scope.shippingAddress;
 };
```

You can do something like this

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.billingAdrEqualsShippingAdr = false;

     $scope.confirmBillingEqualsShipping = true;
     $scope.changeBillingAddress = false;

     $scope.shippingAddress = {};
     $scope.billingAddress = {};

     $scope.setBillingAddress = function (){
       $scope.changeBillingAddress = true;
         $scope.billingAddress = {
           salutation: $scope.shippingAddress.salution,
           prename: $scope.shippingAddress.prename,
           surname: $scope.shippingAddress.surname
         };
     };

     $scope.cancelBillingAddress = function (){
       $scope.changeBillingAddress = false;
         //$scope.billingAddress = $scope.shippingAddress;
     };

     $scope.openCompanyModal = function (company){
         $scope.billingAddress = company;
         $scope.shippingAddress = company;
     };

    $scope.submit = function (){

      if (!$scope.changeBillingAddress) {
        // setting shipping and billing address same should be here         
        $scope.billingAddress = $scope.shippingAddress;
      }
      console.log($scope.shippingAddress);
      console.log($scope.billingAddress);
      console.log("Form submitted");
    }
});
```

Comment: thx for the answer. I fixed it by using angular.copy. But your answer helped me to find to the right way